# Model Factory not calling from Controller

Tags: ajax, newsletter, magento2.2.4

I am creating simple ajax newsletter module, but default controller of magento not going in Model.

```
<?php
    /**
     *
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    namespace Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber;

    use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface as CustomerAccountManagement;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;

    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     */
    class NewAction extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber
    {
        /**
         * @var CustomerAccountManagement
         */
        protected $customerAccountManagement;

        /**
         * Initialize dependencies.
         *
         * @param Context $context
         * @param SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
         * @param Session $customerSession
         * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
         * @param CustomerUrl $customerUrl
         * @param CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement
         */
        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
            Session $customerSession,
            StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
            CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement
        ) {
            $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
            parent::__construct(
                $context,
                $subscriberFactory,
                $customerSession,
                $storeManager,
                $customerUrl
            );
        }

        /**
         * Validates that the email address isn't being used by a different account.
         *
         * @param string $email
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
         * @return void
         */
        protected function validateEmailAvailable($email)
        {
            $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
            if ($this->_customerSession->getCustomerDataObject()->getEmail() !== $email
                && !$this->customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable($email, $websiteId)
            ) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('This email address is already assigned to another user.')
                );
            }
        }

        /**
         * Validates that if the current user is a guest, that they can subscribe to a newsletter.
         *
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
         * @return void
         */
        protected function validateGuestSubscription()
        {
            if ($this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class)
                    ->getValue(
                        \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::XML_PATH_ALLOW_GUEST_SUBSCRIBE_FLAG,
                        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                    ) != 1
                && !$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()
            ) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __(
                        'Sorry, but the administrator denied subscription for guests. Please <a href="%1">register</a>.',
                        $this->_customerUrl->getRegisterUrl()
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        /**
         * Validates the format of the email address
         *
         * @param string $email
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
         * @return void
         */
        protected function validateEmailFormat($email)
        {
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($email, \Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress::class)) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Please enter a valid email address.'));
            }
        }

        /**
         * New subscription action
         *
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
         * @return void
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
                $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email');

                try {
                    $this->validateEmailFormat($email);
                    $this->validateGuestSubscription();
                    $this->validateEmailAvailable($email);

                    $subscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
                    if ($subscriber->getId()
                        && $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED
                    ) {
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                            __('This email address is already subscribed.')
                        );
                    }

                    $status = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
                    if ($status == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The confirmation request has been sent.'));
                    } else {
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
                    }
                } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addException(
                        $e,
                        __('There was a problem with the subscription: %1', $e->getMessage())
                    );
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'));
                }
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
        }
    }
```

Comment: please provide full code of controller.

Comment: Its default controller Magento Newsletter New Action

Comment: If you still want I have updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue by changing redirect code with the following -

```
return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData($response);
```

More changes were made, but primary was the code need to be sent to json.